# Do CRITICAL_SECTION structures need to be aligned?

Tags: memory-management, windows-10, alignment, critical-section

Having a strange situation where an application (in C) is using Critical Sections. On Windows 10 and Server 2016 getting random hangs with a thread waiting for on an EnterCriticalSection.  Since it is so random it is very hard to debug. I have gone over the code a million times to make sure there is a Leave to match each Enter.

However, I know that things have changed a lot in Windows 10.  Do CRITICAL_SECTION structures need to be aligned 16?  I could not see any documentation saying they do. However, Atomic structures need to be and I am wondering if Critical Sections in Windows 10 use Atomic structures internally?

Comment: Any alignment requirements beyond natural alignment will be explicitly declared with `DECLSPEC_ALIGN`. The debugger will tell you who owns the critical section - you can use that to investigate why the owner didn't leave.

Comment: I can't find any documentation suggesting that CRITICAL_SECTION structures need to be specially aligned, so maybe they don't. If they did, probably a lot of people would be having problems.